# Answer heights get muddled after a refresh & reorder

Tags: bug, design, answers, android-app

Reproduced in Android app v1.0.48 on a HTC One running Android 4.4.3:

1. Find a question meeting the following conditions:

   - It has two answers.
   - In the order they appear, the first answer is short. The second answer is long.
2. Now do something to reorder the answers the other way around: vote as necessary.
3. Refresh the answer list.

The answers will now get reordered. The long answer will be the first answer. The short answer will come second... but its answer pane will be as tall as the long answer's. (Presumably, it got reused and was never shrunk to the shorter question's size.)

Here's a screenshot of the bug acting on the shorter answer (click for the full view):

[image]

Comment: This will be fixed in a big update I'm working on now (we're redoing the Q&A page, basically) -- I'll leave it be until that update is out.

Comment: I'm flagging this as "cannot be repro'd" since the app is now showing both Q&A on a single thread. If this *particular issue* still happens on the new Q&A page, consider updating the details.

Comment: @AndrewT Good call. I'm voting to close it for the no-repro close reason.