# Refreshing a question in the new UI currently gets jumbly, and winds up with oddly sized posts

Tags: bug, questions, android-app

I noticed something in Android app v1.0.50 (running on a HTC One with Android 4.4.3) when refreshing [this meta question](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5001/start-retagging-the-wod-questions-aka-editors-the-retaggening):

1. Load that question ↑ since this is an ideal one to demonstrate the issue here. Scroll down, so that each individual answer loads.
2. Scroll back to the top and refresh.
3. The answers reload in the current jumbly fashion (which is ok). When it's finished reloading, the view's probably scrolled to the middle of one of the answers, rather than the top of the question, where you were originally when you reloaded (which is not ideal).
4. Possibly because of [something like this bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238946/answer-heights-get-muddled-after-a-refresh-reorder), now various loaded answers might be stretched to take up excessive height beyond what their content needs.

Comment: I've noticed this too, I think it's to do with a bit too strict recycling of the cells in the lists. Thanks for posting a great repro for it! Looking into it.

Comment: @Kasra As a second repro, when I visit [this link](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/96882?noredirect=1) (to get to a notification of a comment), there is _one very long answer_ and all the answers are quite short. But several answers, each time, have a _very tall_ container. (Especially the one right below that comment.)